# How to embed sound files contents into the .py file (e.g. a base64-encoded string??)

Tags: python, base64, playsound

I want to play a sound on my app when it's .exe but from another computer I can't do that because the path to the sound isn't right so the sound does not play. I was wondering if there's a way to embed the file content into the .py file like the title suggest maybe a base64-encoded string ??

Btw I use playsound library if that matters I just do `playsound('mysound.mp4')`

Comment: Can you post your entire code into the question body?

Answer (score 1):

So the easiest approach to this is to not hand over just the EXE but rather an EXE + folder containing files. If you want to get clever then you can have the program create this folder when it cannot find one. And then let the user submit sound files to the folder. Then you can use the `os` module to find this folder regardless how your friend's computer is configured and read from it.

See this example (in windows for python3):

```
from playsound import playsound
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    audio_file = os.path.dirname(__file__) + '\\Linkin_Park_In_the_End.mp3'
    playsound(audio_file)
```

So this code basically finds what folder the program is located in and then attempts to detect the sound file its looking for (in this is a linkin park mp3 file).

Now if you really want to store the mp3 file in source I suppose that can still be done. But could be effortful.

Note if you are reading this answer please do the following to get it to work.

```
python3 -m pip uninstall playsound 
python3 -m pip install playsound==1.2.2
```

Comment: that's great but what if the user don't have the sound file ? Like It will play on his computer but he doesn't possess the file

Comment: then he needs to get the file. like thats part of your program is the sound file. and installation doesn't just mean handing an exe it means handing an exe with a folder. you can make an installer whose job is basically to decrypt some .tar file into the individual music files and then make a folder and put the music files into the folder so the program can find them. Then when you hand your program to the user you don't send them the exe rather you send an installer which creates the exe + the folder. Or if you want to be really clever you'd send a downloader+installer